# Install gcc and g++ version < 6 in fedora 27

Tags: linux, tensorflow, fedora

I am installing cuda and tensorflow-gpu on fedora 27. But for building binaries of tensorflow it requires gcc and g++ of version less than 6. Fedora comes with already installed gcc and g++ of version 7.3.1 . Can anyone help me with installing  gcc and g++ of older versions ? I've already tried :

```
sudo dnf install compat-gcc-<version>
```

but that didn't work.

Comment: Have you tried with GCC 7. It probably would work

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Extra compilers → Available for Fedora 27 and other Fedora versions are :

1. gcc53-c++-5.3.0-1.el6.x86_64.rpm → https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNbTBneHgwSzBodFE/view?usp=sharing : Download and install : `# cd Downloads/ && yum install ./gcc53-c++-5.3.0-1.el6.x86_64.rpm` ..... Provides `/usr/bin/{gcc53, g++53}`.
2. gcc49-c++-4.9.3-1.el6.x86_64.rpm https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Pwq1ua80dGM72i7rpDNAIIdfcR1WK-hG/view?usp=sharing → Provides /usr/bin/{gcc49, g++49}.
3. gcc63-c++-6.3.0-1.el7.x86_64.rpm https://drive.google.com/file/d/1t4WrgvpEP-6_NN3qMJhz9MS3CJhHrHKc/view?usp=sharing → Provides /usr/bin/{gcc63, g++63}.
4. gcc34-3.4.6-20.SL7.x86_64.rpm, gcc34-c++-3.4.6-20.SL7.x86_64.rpm
   https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B7S255p3kFXNSXBic2V4ekN0Slk?usp=sharing
5. gcc45-c++-4.5.4-1.el7.x86_64.rpm https://drive.google.com/file/d/15aRg-BPhuyaEyZA9Jy-iAyC21_pwN7nD/view?usp=sharing → Provides /usr/bin/{gcc45, g++45, gfortran45}
6. gcc73-c++-7.3.0-1.el7.x86_64.rpm
   https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PgwCP5tu8D0EJbJVTqJd7Vg8dJ4l4noi/view?usp=sharing → Provides /usr/bin/{gcc73, g++73}

Note : You can have as many gcc versions as you want, installed at the same time. Important is the default compiler : `# dnf install gcc-c++`

Comment: Is there one of these for gcc7?

Comment: @nitronoid : The default Fedora 27 compiler *is* gcc-7 : `# dnf install gcc-c++` .... gcc7 for all versions, Fedora 21 .. 29 : gcc73-c++-7.3.0-1.el7.x86_64.rpm https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PgwCP5tu8D0EJbJVTqJd7Vg8dJ4l4noi/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Yup, I'm on fedora 28 however, which comes with gcc-8, but would like gcc-7. Thanks for the link!

Comment: I'm actually on fedora 31 and I would like to have gcc-8, I tried downloading from pkgs.org but I'm stuck in a dependencies hell, a self contained package like those you linked would really be appreciated